# Updating models periodically (intervals of time) in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, rubygems

I have a rails app that is essentially running a game. I need to "recharge" certain attributes of records in my database after a certain amount of time (let's say, x seconds). What would the best way to do this be? Do I need to use a gem?

I am using rails 4.2.6, ruby 2.3.0, and active record for my ORM.

Comment: You need to accomplish this once in every x seconds? Or x seconds after some event? Is it user specific? Or you need to update all records irrespective of any conditions?

Comment: I need to do it every x seconds if a boolean is set to true. It is only for a subset of the users (active characters, not ones we have deemed "dead").

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the models you want to "refresh", you can setup static methods :

```
# app/models/product.rb

class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
 // some code

 def self.refresh_stocks
   // some code
 end

 def self.refresh_thumbnails
   // some code
 end

end
```

Then, I suggest you to define some [custom rake tasks](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/command_line.html#custom-rake-tasks):

```
# lib/tasks/myapp.rake
namespace :myapp do
  namespace :products do
    desc 'Refresh products'
    task refresh: :environment do
      Product.refresh_stocks
      Product.refresh_thumbnails
    end
  end
end
```

Then, you can use the whenever gem to setup your scheduling in your cron tab thanks to a nice dsl:

```
# config.schedule.rb
every 1.hour do
  rake "myapp:products:refresh"
end
```

A big win is when you use [capistrano](https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano) to deploy your app: In that case use the [whenever capistrano integration](https://github.com/javan/whenever#capistrano-integration) to automatically refresh you cron tab at each deployment.

Happy scheduling